# CSS nav link styling: remove styling of other element & remove double border when hovered on selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have:

- A navbar (div > ul > li) with a few navigational links in it.
- A border added on hover

  ```
  .my-nav > li:hover {
      border-bottom: 0.2em solid white;
  }
  ```
- An AngularJS directive which applies the below class to whichever is the active page (using routes)

  ```
  .active-tab {
      border-bottom: 0.2em solid white;    
      font-weight: bold;
  }
  ```

My issues are:

1. If I'm on active-tab "A" and hover onto active tab "B", I want all styling removed from "A" but I have no idea how to approach.
2. If I hover on the active page (which already has active-tab applied to it, it doubles the thickness of the border.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or at the least show a live site where the issue is replicated?

Comment: Or, in other words, what have you tried so far? This goes beyond just CSS - so, you either need to research how to use various frameworks that could help you: jQuery or bootstrap or angular with angular.ui. Otherwise, the question is too broad.

Comment: @skv Sure you can see the exact issue over on http://letsdolunch.today

Comment: @NewDev I have tried a lot but unable to resolve either issue. Whole thing is in AngularJS, and as mentioned it's an AngularJS directive which dictates the usage of the active-tab CSS class... My CSS is weak comparatively, but there's gotta be a way to resolve the double thickness problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use the removeClass() function on the other elements where you are adding the class in your directive.

As an example, if all other are anchor tags you could use the following code:-

```
element.parent().find("a").removeClass("active-tab");        //add this to remove class from other elements
element.addClass("active-tab");          //you already have this
```

Check out this plnkr:- http://plnkr.co/edit/Re6EAL6XRsKHqqHPq5kw?p=preview

As for your border problem, as skv said in his answer, you have set the border on both the element and hover styles. Just remove the border from hover and it'll work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for doubling the border on the active link, you'd use:

```
.active-tab:hover {
  border-bottom: 0.4em solid white;
}
```

And adjust the width to taste. For removing the styling for "A" while "B" is hovered, you'd likely need a javascript solution. Something like this (using jQuery):

```
$('.my-nav > li:not(.active-tab)').hover(function(){
  $('.my-nav > li.active-tab').css({ "border-bottom": "none", "font-weight": "normal"});
}, function(){
  $('.my-nav > li.active-tab').css({ "border-bottom": "0.2em solid white", "font-weight": "bold"});
});
```

Then again, you might want to ask why you want that functionality, as it's not a huge deal to leave the styling on the active tab or just create slightly different styling than the hover class.

Comment: Thanks. For the border, it's doubling itself and I *don't* want it to. You can see the behavior first hand over at http://letsdolunch.today ... as for hover issue, I want it because it looks silly the way it is now, as you can see for yourself :P Your JS solution makes sense... but I'm not quite sure how to tackle it given how my stuff is setup. I'll give it a whirl, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

The doubling is happening because on one (Angular) side you are setting a bottom border for `li>a` element and on the other (index.css) you are setting it at the `li` you can change it to `.my-nav>li>a:hover` and you would have the issue disappearing.

Regarding the second part or making the active tab disappear, well thats not a default behaviour on the internet (the active is always highlighted) because it is a user experience metric of telling the user where they are.  If you still want to achieve that you can use Javascript suggested by the previous answerer

The code can just sit on the header file without any external files i.e. you could just copy and paste it just above `</head>` tag.